# Sorting a list of CSVRecords (apache commons)

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I got this CSV file:

```
User ID,First Name
3,David 
4,Ruby 
10,Ruby
```

which I would like to order in ascending order using the following method:

```
@Override
    public void sort(InputStream in, OutputStream out, String field_name, Comparator<CSVRecord> comparator) throws IOException {

     Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);  
     Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(inputStreamReader);

     List<CSVRecord> csvRecordsList = Lists.newArrayList(csvRecords);
     Collections.sort(csvRecordsList,comparator);

     Writer outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
     CSVPrinter cvsPrinter = CSVFormat.RFC4180.print(outputStreamWriter); 
     cvsPrinter.printRecords(csvRecordsList);
     cvsPrinter.flush();
     cvsPrinter.close();
```

The problem is that Collections.sort doesn't do anything. This is the comparable I provide as a parameter:

```
 Comparator<CSVRecord> comparator = (op1,op2) -> op2.get(field).compareTo(op1.get(field));
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I got this as output if I run that code:
4,"Ruby "
3,"David "
10,"Ruby "

Comment: how is `field` defined?

Comment: like this: final String field = "User ID";

Comment: An element of the list is printed like this: 
CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={User ID=0, First Name=1}, recordNumber=1, values=[3, David]]

Comment: The problem is that the ID 10 is read like 1. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSVRecord.get()` returns a `String` so you're actually calling `String.compareTo` instead of `Integer.compareTo` in your comparator. Try this instead:

```
Comparator<CSVRecord> comparator = (op1,op2) -> Integer.valueOf(op2.get(field)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(op1.get(field)));
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Can you please tell me why using String.compareTo was a problem? It worked fine for digits from 0-9.

Comment: Moreover, do you know how can I write the original CSV header even in output?

Comment: `String.compareTo` doesn't interpret the numbers in your strings as numbers but as individual numbers. Think of it as comparing two arrays element by element for the same index. So when "6" is compared to "10" the characters at position 0 will be compared and since '1' is less than '6' the order is given as it is.

Comment: It looks like you can use [`CSVRecord.toMap()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html#toMap--) to work out a solution to print the original headers.

Comment: Many many thanks! I've just spent a couple of hours on this :)